# Const error with this

Tags: c++, constants

This is my code:

```
bool State::operator==(const State& s) const
{
    bool flag=true;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(s.GetboardEl(i,j)!=board[i][j]){
                flag=false;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

`getBoardE`l is a function in State class which returns an element from board(int[][]). I get this ERROR even if i'm using const before the brackets({)
:

> error: passing 'const State' as 'this' argument of 'int State::GetboardEl(int, int)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|

Comment: Show the full code... How can we say whether you're calling `GetboardEl()` correctly if you don't show it?

Comment: Change `int State::GetboardEl(int, int)` to `int State::GetboardEl(int, int) const`

Comment: @PaulR seems to work Thank you

Comment: @JJohnarios: jolly good - make sure you understand why the `const` is needed and then this shouldn't trip you up again in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the member function `getBoardEl` is a non-`const` member function.

You should definitely change that to a `const` member function since the name implies it is a *get* function not a *set* function.

That would resolve the compiler error.

Another way to resolve the error is to use the member variable directly, as you have for `this`.

```
if ( s.board[i][j] != this->board[i][j] ) {
```